# How can I update data into a table resulting from a query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I query this table here

```
SELECT
  a.ESN,
  b.URL,
  a.Status,
  a.GroupID,
  a.RouteID
FROM STx a
  LEFT JOIN Routes b
    ON a.RouteID = b.RouteID
WHERE a.GroupID = 39
    AND a.Status = "Provisioned"
order by a.ESN;
```

now from the result set of this , I'd like to modify **url** of table **Routes** to **test** for all the rows in the **url** column from the result of the first query .. how can I do that in a query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update Routes set url = 'test' 
where id in (
    select b.id 
    from Stx a left join routes b on a.routeid = b.routeid 
    where a.groupid = 39 and a.status = 'Provisioned'
);
```

Comment: but b.id is only recognized within the select statement

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to update the URL column to 'Test' for all the results that you get from your original query.

```
UPDATE Routes
SET URL = 'Test'
FROM STx AS A
LEFT JOIN Routes AS B
ON a.RouteID = b.RouteID
WHERE a.GroupID = 39 AND a.Status = 'Provisioned'
```

Comment: You only want it to apply to rows where URL IS NULL? Then add an extra check to the WHERE clause like AND b.URL IS NULL